# account factory for terraform (AWS) - recreate account customization pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I added a new Account request through the AFT module (https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-terraform-aft-account-request). The Account is in place and I can see it in AWS Organization in the Master Account. However, the Code Pipeline is missing in the AFT Account. I did provision a few more Accounts earlier and those Code Pipelines do exist. Is there a way I can re-trigger the request just to create the missing Code Pipeline for this specific Account. Any help will be much appreciated ?

I have provisioned the Code Pipelines using https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-terraform-aft-account-request to vend out new AWS accounts. This AFT module creates a AWS Code Pipeline for each new Account provisioned to push customizations to that particular account. However, this Code Pipeline was not created for one of the Accounts. The Account details are visible in aft-account-request dynamo db & aft-account-request-metadata dynamo db tables. I want to re-trigger the framework to create this missing account specific Code Pipeline ?

Comment: You can try to retrigger the related step functions

Comment: I executed the aft-account-request code pipeline job which internally invokes the aft-account-provisioning-framework step function but the account pipeline was still not created. Wondering if I should remove the account entry from dynamo db tables and re-run the aft-account-provisioning-framework ? Still not sure which table should that be removed from aft-request or aft-request-metadata ?

Comment: Didn't you find anything in logs? Someone is having a similar issue and the _free_ support recommends the following to try to identify the root cause: https://github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-control_tower_account_factory/issues/366#issuecomment-1622188524